# Qt + VTK +Ubuntu on VirtualBox

Tags: qt, ubuntu, virtualbox, vtk

I need to run a **Qt project with VTK on Ubuntu** and I'm using VirtualBox, but I have an error:

> GL version 2.1 with the gpu_shader4 extension is not supported by your
>   graphics driver but is required for the new OpenGL rendering backend.
>   Please update your OpenGL driver. If you are using Mesa please make
>   sure you have version 10.6.5 or later and make sure your driver in
>   Mesa supports OpenGL 3.2.

Comment: 1) This is the wrong place to ask this .. 2) Check this out .. It helped me .. https://askubuntu.com/questions/858407/how-to-update-to-latest-opengl-version-on-virtualbox-ubuntu-linux-machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent version of VTK use a [new rendering backend](https://blog.kitware.com/new-opengl-rendering-in-vtk/) by default. In the CMake cache file used to configure your build, the corresponding cmake variable VTK_RENDERING_BACKEND has the value "OpenGL2" which assumes a minimum OpenGL API version of 2.1. But the problem is that a vanilla installation of VirtualBox does not grant access to 3D acceleration by default as it cannot presumably infer these informations from the host system.

So I think that you have several options here depending on your needs and constraints, you could install the VirtualBox Guest Additions to enable [hardware 3D acceleration](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-video), allow access to a newer version of the OpenGL API and use in the end the host to performs the requested 3D operations. You could also use a recent version of the [Mesa3D library](https://www.mesa3d.org/) to performs the needed 3D operations on the CPU (to choose preferably if you don't have graphics hardware on the host). For a presentation of its features, you can take a look [here](https://mesamatrix.net/)